# How to create a picture?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Hi I have a question about a windows phone 7 app.

I would like to create a picture or an area in an app where I can for example, add font or other elements like a circle.

Can anyone show me an example or some code? Or is it not possible?
I would like a silverlight app, not XNA

Comment: Are you asking how to add a circle/text to a picture?

Comment: yes, but the image must not exist before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do advanced image creation/manipulation using [.NET Image Tools for Silverlight](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/).